# lapply subsetting to a list of data frames

Tags: r, logic, subset, lapply

I have a list of data frames that look like that

```
$ list
$gnl_4935
          V1     V2    V3               V4    V5  
99  gnl_4935 -63.23  -1.4 1.05263157894737 MS_run03
100 gnl_4935 -61.89 -1.06             1.25 MS_run03
101 gnl_4935 -51.29 -1.31  1.0989010989011 MS_run03
102 gnl_4935 -39.09 -1.05 1.44927536231884 MS_run03


$gnl_4990
          V1     V2    V3               V4   V5      
99  gnl_4897 -45.82  -1.4 1.05263157894737 MS_run03
100 gnl_4897 -33.85 -1.06             1.25 MS_run03
101 gnl_4897 -27.14 -1.31  1.0989010989011 MS_run03


$gnl_5098
       V1     V2    V3           V4         V5     
99  PSE_4 -50.49  -1.4 1.05263157894737 MS_run03
100 PSE_4 -39.48 -1.06             1.25 MS_run03
```

I want to apply a function that perform different operation on different columns. Therefore, in the function I subset the data frames as reported below:

```
> Prop<- function (data, clmn)
+                 {ratio<-data[ ,clmn]
+                    complete <- c(ratio[ratio!=0],unique(ratio[ratio==0]))}
```

I want to subset column 2:

```
lapply(list, Prop, 2)
```

I would expect:

```
$gnl_4935
-63.23 -61.89 -51.29 -39.09 

$gnl_4990
-45.82 -33.85 -27.14 

$gnl_5098
-50.49 -39.48
```

But I get:

```
$gnl_4935
99 97 81 49

$gnl_4990
67 38 19 

$gnl_5098
76 52
```

When I test just the subsetting:

```
ratio<-data[ ,clmn]
```

I obtain the following results:

```
$gnl_4935
[1] -63.23 -61.89 -51.29 -39.09
106 Levels: -20.4 -21.1 -21.23 -21.37 -21.93 -22.24 -22.52 -22.56 -24.05 -24.69 -24.83 -24.85 -25.25 -25.8 -26.44 ... -83.33


$gnl_4990
[1] -45.82 -33.85 -27.4 
106 Levels: -20.4 -21.1 -21.23 -21.37 -21.93 -22.24 -22.52 -22.56 -24.05 -24.69 -24.83 -24.85 -25.25 -25.8 -26.44 ... -83.33


$gnl_5098
[1] -50.49 -39.48
106 Levels: -20.4 -21.1 -21.23 -21.37 -21.93 -22.24 -22.52 -22.56 -24.05 -24.69 -24.83 -24.85 -25.25 -25.8 -26.44 ... -83.33
```

Therefore, I really do not understand where do the numbers of the full function come from.
Someone has an explanation?

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you sure that `ratio` is of class numeric? Try to change the first line to `ratio <- as.numeric(data[ ,clmn])`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that the subsetting works, please refer to the edited question. However, when I try to apply logical condition to the subsetted object something I cannot understand happen. I tried what you suggested, but I get the same problem.

Comment: I'm sure I'm overlooking something trivial..

Comment: I think the problem is that you have a factor instead of numeric vector (as you can see from "106 Levels:..." in the output). So you are getting the factor position rather than the numeric value. Weird that as.numeric does not solve this... Can you please use as.numeric as in my earlier comment and then update the post with the output (printing `ratio`).

Comment: Ok, I see. But I do not understand the reason. Do you have any useful link/reference I could consult to understand? Thanks very much.

Comment: The reason is that the column V2 is a factor, which is a special structure that R uses (you can read ?factor for some more info). A good guide for subsetting factors etc is here http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#data-types. Now, I don't know why V2 in your data is of class factor to start with. This will be due to some code that you ran earlier, when you generated it, I suppose...

Comment: You'll have to use `as.numeric(as.character(x))` to convert from factor to numeric.

Comment: yes I already figured it out, thanks!